# Which is the earliest Apple TV that can mirror an iPad?

Tags: ipad, appletv, mirroring

So, I need to mirror an iPad Air 2 (not just spare apps, the whole screen and audio) wirelessly to a projector, and I was thinking of buying an Apple TV. However, since the current version is so expensive, I thought of buying an older one (say, TV 3rd Gen version A1427, A1469 or 2nd Gen). Somehow, I couldn't find this in the Apple help (I guess... because they update it to the latest version, sometimes "hiding" previous ones).

Which is the *earliest* version that can (decently) screen mirror an iPad?

Comment: While @grgarside is correct, I would still recommend you purchasing an Apple TV 3 if possible. You can pick these up at reasonable prices. You may also have the option of purchasing a current model that's been refurbished by Apple (but you would have to check your local Apple website to check on availability (usually at the bottom of the main page you'll see a link for _Refurbished and Clearance_ stock.

Comment: Thanks @Monomeeth for your comment. Although, do you have a reason why to get a newer version? Is it faster, does it have a less laggy experience, etc? Plus, yeah, I keep looking at the refurbished section for my country, although the last time I say it (Apple TV 3 with a 14% discount), it disappeared in a matter of minutes

Comment: Well, my preference for an Apple TV 3 is based on a few things. Firstly, it supports 1080p video (which may be important depending on the projector you're using), while the Apple TV 2 is limited to 720p video. Also the ATV3 has 512MB RAM compared to the ATV2's 256 MB RAM. The ATV3 has bluetooth, the ATV2 does not. The maximum OS for the ATV2 is Apple TV 6.2, while for the ATV 3 it is still capable of running the current OS. There are other differences, but basically an ATV3 is a better model all round _unless_ you want to jailbreak it, in which case the ATV2 would be a better option.

Comment: Well, @Monomeeth, you convinced me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Apple TV 2** is the earliest Apple TV that supports AirPlay Mirroring, being the earliest Apple TV capable of installing Software Update 4.4, which added the feature.

> AirPlay Mirroring: Wirelessly stream what's on your iPhone 4S or iPad 2 screen to your HDTV.

<sup>https://support.apple.com/kb/HT202157</sup>

Comment: Hey, thanks @grgarside! I actually thought mirroring was only available from the latest TV 3, but my guts told me I had to ask first. Thanks again!